# C# Hiding Array of Buttons/Labels/TextBoxes

Tags: c#

I created Array of Buttons/Labels/TextBoxes/Panels programatically. My question is how to hide those array after some event. Is there a single line of command? like for example of MyArray.Sum() which give you the sum of values inside an array. I tried MyArray.Hide() but no command for this one. Thanks.

Comment: Just use `foreach()` (preferred), or maybe `Select().ToList()` (abuse, as you're not selecting anything). Try searching.

Comment: @CodeCaster I hate such method like for... for(i=1;i<=100;i++) { MyArray[i].Visible=false;}. No shorter method for this one.

Comment: What "such method" do you mean and why do you hate it?

Comment: What's point in hating here. I don't understand

Comment: because most of the time I keep repeating those method of for & foreach. I think no single line of command regarding hiding arrays

Comment: @CodeCaster I hate such method like for... for(i=1;i<=100;i++) { MyArray[i].Visible=false;}. No shorter method for this one

Comment: That's why I suggested `foreach()`. Shorter code isn't always better.

Comment: If you do not want to have to write a loop each time you want to do this just write your own method which uses the loop inside the method body and call the method with the used parameters, you just have to write the loop one time and then you can call a one-liner. For example: void HideControls(Control[] arrayOfControls) { foreach (Control c in arrayOfControls) { c.visible = false; } } then later when you need to use it just call your method (which indeed is shorter than always writing the functionality again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
foreach(var x in MyArray)
{
    x.Visible = false;
}
```

If you want a method call you can create an extension method:

```
namespace Extensions
{
    public static class FormExtensions
    {
        public static void HideAll(this Control[] controls)
        {
            foreach(var control in controls)
            {
                control.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyArray.HideAll();
```

Either way, please update your question with more details and some code.

Comment: sorry man but where to add a method? I'm just a newbie in C#. after namespace? public partial class? or public form..

Comment: See my edit - the code goes in a new `FormExtensions.cs` file. In your class where you want to call HideAll() add `using Extensions;`.

Comment: i tried but it says null reference in "control.Visible = false;"

Comment: Then one of your controls must be `null`.

Comment: is this correct namespace Extensions { public static class FormExtensions { public static void HideAll(this Control[] controls) { foreach (var control in controls) { control.Visible = false; } } } } namespace House_Estimator { public partial class FormHouseEstimator : Form { // // public FormHouseEstimator() { InitializeComponent(); //code } } }

Comment: You need to show us where you are adding controls to the array and where you're calling `HideAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Array.ForEach(MyArray, c => c.Hide());
```

but a `foreach` is not really worse and still works if you'll change it to a list:

```
foreach (Control c in MyArray) c.Hide();
```

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Anyway What is .Hide()?

Comment: @RahulNikate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think OP is looking for answer in WebForms and not in WinForms

Comment: @RahulNikate: why do you think that? OP hasn't mentioned ASP.NET and all mentioned controls also exist in winforms. But `Hide` is a method that exists only in winforms and not in ASP.NET.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes you are right. It's OP fault. He should mention it in tags. But one of his comment where he wrote MyArray[i].Visible=false;. So I guessed it to ASP.Net i.e. WebForms

Comment: @RahulNikate: why, winforms also has the [`Visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which has a similar functionaliy.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok. Thank You. I was not aware of `Visible` in WinForms

Answer (score 0):

You could update the structure of your UI so as to add your hideable elements to a parent Panel/Container of some sort. This way you only ever have to worry about showing/hiding the parent and not tracking a list.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use a regular for each loop:

```
//Create an action that hides your control
Action<Control> HideControlAction = new Action<int>(HideControl);
//Call your action on each member of MyArray
Array.ForEach(MyArray, action);
```

Define your action method:

```
private static void HideControl(Control control)
{
      control.Visible = false;
}
```

However it does the exact same thing as

```
foreach(Control control in MyArray)
{
    control.Visible=false ;
}
```

Comment: is this correct

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class FormExtensions
    {
        public static void HideAll(this Control[] controls)
        {
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                control.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace House_Estimator
{
    public partial class FormHouseEstimator : Form
    {
        //
        //

        public FormHouseEstimator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //code
        }
    }
}